# i can not run Xampp IDE

Tags: xampp

i have this error:

```
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp$ sudo ./xampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.1-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server with SSL is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

based of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533439/xampp-on-debian7-starting-apache-fails) to this post:

[XAMPP on Debian7 starting Apache fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533439/xampp-on-debian7-starting-apache-fails)

> when debian7 start,it will start apache2. so you should stop it
>   first,than try to start lampp.
>
> `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop /opt/lampp/lampp restart`
>
> that maybe work.try it.

i get this feedback:

```
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp/bin$ /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
[ ok ] Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp/bin$ /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.1-0...
You need to be root to perform this action.
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp/bin$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
[ ok ] Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp/bin$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.1-0...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server with SSL is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp/bin$
```

so again i have this problem

**Update:**

By this instructions my problem solved:

> 1.Open the file /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf Search the "Listen 80" and change it to some other port (e.g. Listen 2145) (Line No. 40)
>   2. Open the file /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf Search the "Listen 443" and change it to some other port (e.g. Listen 16443)
>   (Line No. 39)
>   3. Open the file /opt/lampp/lampp Search for the port "testport 80" and replace it to "testport 2145".
>   4.Also change the "testport 443" to "testport 16443". (Happens to be the Line No. 197, 214)
>   5.Now go and run /opt/lampp/lampp start. (It should work now).

now i get this feedback:

```
so@so-notebook:/opt/lampp/bin$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.1-0...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Thanks [@vishnu-vidhyadhran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9084944/vishnu-vidhyadhran).

but i can not run Xampp IDE in my Ubuntu OS and see its GUI‌!!!

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I do this :

```
sudo nano  /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

and add this scripts into the ***/usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop*** file like this :

[image]

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
```

[image]

so the problem solved and i can see the Xampp IDE, but there must be some problem with http://localhost:80/dashboard/ as default xampp server and must be changed to http://localhost:2145/dashboard/ as you can see here:

[image]
[image]

Also the WWW folder as document-root folder is :

> /opt/lampp/htdocs